# Can't Establish connection to MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been trying to establish a connection to a SQL Server 2008 but i get a return message saying:

> Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => -1 [code] => -1 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network
>   Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server
>   Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
>   [xFFFFFFFF]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] =>
>   0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login
>   timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE]
>   => 08001 [1] => -1 [code] => -1 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or
>   not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. )

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "SERV002\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"YSHSDB", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:** I have fixed this by installing xampp lite onto my server 2003 running the SQL server however, I would still like to be able to access the SQL server if the web services is running on another machine.

Comment: This question has already been Answered 3 hrs ago. Why ask again?

Comment: ok no problem. Will not happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your **Server Configuration Manager**
[Server Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YesfH.png)

Under SQL Server Network Configuration
Click on **Protocols for SQLEXPRESS**

Rightclick and access Properties of TCP/IP

Select the **IP Addresses** **Tab**

Now configure all the **TCP Port**(s) to the port you are using in your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious error here is that your SQL server is not running or is not configured to allow remote connections (I think that is the default for SqlExpress)

You will need to open your Sql Connection Manager and change the settings for TCP connections to make them available for remote connections.  You may also have a firewall blocking your Sql Connection somewhere.  Make sure port 1433 is exposed in any fire wall.

Comment: thanks I will look at the firewall setting. SQL has remote connections enabled.

Comment: my firewall is disable on the server running sql.